# Passing output of a method to another method in java

Tags: java, methods

Hi I am new to java and am trying to figure out how I pass on the out put of on method to another method. Please see in below code.

```
public class Myclass 
{
    private double test1input;
    private int test2input;

    public void settest1input(double test1inputIn)
    {
        test1input = test1inputIn;
    }

    public void settest2input(int test2inputIn)
    {
        test2input = test2inputIn;
    }

    public String test1(double test1inputIn)
    {
        if (test1inputIn<6) 
        {
             return("small");
        }
        else 
        {
            return("large");
        }

    }

    public boolean test2(int test2inputIn) 
    {
        if (test2inputIn<500) 
        {
            return false;
        }
        else 
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public String outputMessage() 
    {
        String Message1 = test1();
        boolean Message2 = test2();

        return ("This is a test = "+Message1+"\n"+"This is a test = "+Message2);

    }
}
```

Any help here would be much appreciated. What I'm trying to achieve is that outputMessage() uses  the return messages of test1() and test2() to return another message.

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: `test1` and `test2` both require a parameter. You don't pass any. This code won't compile.

Comment: Call the methods with parameters e.g. `String Message1 = test1(10);
        boolean Message2 = test2(1000);`. Also, follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) e.g. `Message1` should be named as `message1` and `Message2` should be named as `message2`.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, in your `outputMessage()` method: You are calling a method, so you should first put something a double in the parentheses so you get an value for Message1 and Message 2. Second, if you want to see your code be run, create a main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Myclass m = new Myclass();
    System.out.println(m.outputMessage());
}
```

Your `outputMessage()` should look like this:

```
public String outputMessage() {
    String Message1 = test1(5.1); // These are just test numbers, you can put whatever
    boolean Message2 = test2(12341234); // numbers you want 

    return ("This is a test = " + Message1 + "\n" + "This is a test = " + Message2);
}
```

Hopefully this solves your problem